# How to use pom.xml/Maven to initialize a local thoughtsite (App Engine sample) project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven-2, pom.xml

This sample app ("thoughtsite") for App Engine contains a `pom.xml` in its trunk:

http://code.google.com/p/thoughtsite/source/browse/#svn/trunk

But I don't know what command to run in Maven to set up the project locally. (The README doesn't mention anything about Maven.)

I tried to just import the project code directly into `Eclipse` but it doesn't look like it's in an appropriate format for a direct import. So I assume I need to do something with `Maven` to get it set up correctly. I haven't really used `Maven` before so I'm not sure what command I would need to run to set everything up. The `pom.xml` seems like it downloads a bunch of dependencies for the project like the `Spring` jar files which I don't see anywhere else in the svn repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install maven. (Download it, put it somewhere and set the environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME`). Here are some more [Installation instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation).

Then either a) install [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) and then import the project using "import existing maven project" you should be up and running.

or, b) on the command line, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from inside the project directory and then just import the project as an existing eclipse project

I prefer m2eclipse because it makes eclipse maven-savvy, but many others prefer to just tell eclipse where stuff is from the outside using the command line